# SDK for handwriting input on Android

Tags: android, handwriting

I read that Android provides an API for handwriting input since 1.6 but I can't find it anywhere. Or are there other free / affordable options for handwriting input? I need it for multiple languages including Chinese/Japanese. What do you recommend?

Greetings Andreas

Comment: please refer the link

http://stackoverflow.com/q/9786676/1192775